# Can a Power BI dataset query be used as a data source in a Power App?

Tags: powerbi, powerquery, powerapps

The scenario:

- A dataset is published to the Power BI service
- The dataset contains data that is relevant for a Power App application
- One intended use for the data in the dataset is to populate a drop down/select box in a Power App form

Question:

- Is it possible to use data from a published Power BI dataset in a Power Apps application?
- Is so, how?

Answer (score 1):

One method is doing so via Power Automate.
In Power Automate, within the Power BI connector, you'll find the "Run a query against a dataset" action. Take note: this can only return one table at a time with max of 1,000 rows.
So PowerApps > Power Automate ( > Power BI dataset ) > PowerApps

I've just discovered that yes, you can do this directly in PowerApps. Go to Data > Add data > Connectors and Select Power BI. Once done, you can then use `PowerBI.ExecuteDatasetQuery(<groupId>, <datasetId>, <dax query>)`.
See this other answer for more: [Issues with PowerBI connector in PowerApps](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73472958/issues-with-powerbi-connector-in-powerapps)

Comment: Re. the last option (i.e. `ExecuteDatasetQuery`): Do you know how/if the result of running the query can be used to for instance as a data source for a gallery? Or as a data source for dropdown items?

Comment: Yes, it should be - but you will need to save the results to a collection that then can be used as a datasource for your controls. See the answer in the link in the answer above as an example.